# VBScript + regular expressions: Maching two and three digits

Tags: regex, vbscript

In Windows 7 I use more then 100 services with the same name except an number
In the name, I would like to filter the number behind SVC:. The problem with the pattern is that he doesn't filter 3 digits.So my last number is always 99. How can I change the pattern, so I can filter 1, 2 and 3 digits?

c:\program.exe /SVC:1 /STN:9501

c:\program.exe /SVC:2 /STN:9502
etc.

c:\program.exe /SVC:99 /STN:9599

c:\program.exe /SVC:100 /STN:9600

c:\program.exe /SVC:101 /STN:9601

etc.

```
    For Each objService in colListOfServices
      Set objRegEx = New RegExp 
      objRegEx.IgnoreCase = False
      objRegEx.Pattern = "/SVC\:(.+)?/STN" ' Set pattern.
    If Not IsNull(objService.PathName) Then
      If objRegEx.Test(objService.PathName) Then
        intID = objRegEx.Execute(objService.PathName)(0).SubMatches(0) 
      Else
        intID = 0
      End If
      Else
        intID = 0
      End If

  If intID > intMaxID Then
    intMaxID = intID
  End If

Next

wscript.echo "MaxID: " & intMaxId
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "/SVC\:(.+)?/STN" ' Set pattern.
```

to:

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "/SVC:(\d{2,3})\s*/STN" ' Set pattern.
```

After the last change in the question, the regex is:

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "/SVC:(\d{1,3})\s*/STN" ' Set pattern.
```

Or, if the number of digit is indefined (ie. from 0 to infinity):

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "/SVC:(\d+)\s*/STN" ' Set pattern.
```

Comment: Unfortunately also gives this pattern as the highest number 99

Comment: You are wrong. { n , m } 
 m and n are nonnegative integers. Matches at least n and at most m times. For example, "o{1,3}" matches the first three o's in "fooooood." "o{0,1}" is equivalent to "o?".

Comment: @MarkMunsterman:Strange, it should work and match number that have 2 or 3 digit long. May be there is something else that prevents the match

Comment: @Noodles: Sorry, I don't get you. The regex matches 2 or 3 digit number followed by 0 or more spaces then a slash, what's wrong?

Comment: @Noodles: OK. Please, add the name in the comment in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's going wrong with the following:

If intID > intMaxID Then
   intMaxID = intID
End If

intID = 103 but intMaxID = 99

Comment: @MarkMunsterman, The `Submatches(0)` is a string. The `>` is comparing strings. Use `intID = CLng(objRegEx.Execute(objService.PathName)(0).SubMatches(0))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need for RegEx:

```
Dim d As Double, a() As String

a = Split("Text BLA BLA /SVC:98 /STN", ":")

d = Val(a(UBound(a)))                   ' Example "98 /STN" to 98.0
```